# Phaserjs, filters, save to image cache

Tags: javascript, webgl, web

I've tried to apply a Pixi filter to a image and save it to cache but the image doesn't get saved with the filter.

```
colorMatrix = new PIXI.ColorMatrixFilter();
colorMatrix.matrix = [0,0.0,0.5,-0.2, 0,0,1.0,-0.2, 0.0,0.0,0.5,-0.2, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1]
image = game.make.bitmapData()
image.load("testImage")
image.filters = [colorMatrix]
game.cache.addBitmapData("testImageWIthFilter", image);
```

Is it not possible to save it to cache? The only thing I see is the original image when using the code down below:

```
messageImage = game.add.sprite(0, 0, game.cache.getBitmapData('testImageWIthFilter'))
```

Comment: How are you using the image? We need to see that part of the code also.

Comment: @Katu Updated my question!

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong here..

Comment: @Katu But it doesnt work :)